# React / Express Access to fetch from Origin Blocked by CORS Policy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors

I am trying to learn React and Express. I am trying to allow local file upload from a react component and need Express to catch the file, but no matter what I try, I get:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have installed npm install CORS --save on the Express server. I set a proxy in the React package.json. See below:

```
},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "browserslist": {
```

React is running on port 3000 and Express on 3001.

Here is the component executing the fetch:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddNewItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedFile: null,
      imagePath: ''
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(event.target[0].value)
    console.log(event.target.title.value)
    console.log(event.target.image.value)
    console.log(this.inputNode.value)

    const data = new FormData()
    data.append("image", this.state.selectedFile)

    //const myFileInputs = document.querySelector("input[type='image']");

    fetch('http://localhost:3001', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({ fileName: data.originalname })
      })
  }

  fileSelectedHandler = event => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);

    this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
      loaded: 0,
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Title:</label><br />
          <input type="text" id="title" name="title" ref={node => (this.inputNode = node)} /><br />
          <label>Image:</label><br />
          <input type="file" id="image" name="image" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler}></input>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddNewItem;
```

And here is my Express server:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.' })
})

app.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3001')
})
```

When I start the Express server, I get

```
CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3001
```

in my terminal.

My web page console gives me the following output when I submit the file to the Express server from the React component. See the screen shot:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have been working on this for several hours. Thanks.

After removing the proxy from the React package.json, I get the following in the console:
[image]

Comment: do with any of the one. Remove the proxy from package.json .Or  use the proxy and remove the cros in express .let try this .Don't forget restart the servers both react and express

Comment: @prasanth, I have updated my question to show the new error after removing the proxy from the React package.json. Now I am getting connection refused. I am not sure that I have my url's set correctly in the React fetch call and the Express get call.

Comment: your fetch send a `post` request .But your express only have `app.get('/'` .So please add a `app.post` route

Comment: @prasanth, I am not sure how to code the app.post method. I am going to have to research that. Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Someone down voted my question? Why? I included lots of detail, listed what I have tried. Listed what I was trying to accomplish. Listed all of my code. What's wrong with this question? If you are going to down vote it, at least tell me why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do with any one of them.

1. Remove the proxy from `package.json`
2. **OR** use the proxy and remove the `cors` from express

And

Your fetch send a `method:'POST'` post request. But your express only have `get` request. So you should add `post` route on express like this

**POST route**  [Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

```
app.post('/', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({ msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain POST request' })
})
```